# Spring MVC Internationalization: Content not changing as per the selected language

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, internationalization

I am trying to execute a Spring MVC Internationalization demo program which will display Username and Password on Login page in three different languages i.e English, Italian and German. But on click of other languages also, it is showing the content in English Language only. Please help me to find out what mistake i have done in this program.

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>FirstSpringMVCAnnotations</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  

</web-app>
```

**spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml:**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.demo.controller" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true" />

        <!-- For reading the properties files -->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/message" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/init" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
                <property name="paramName" value="lang"></property>
            </bean>
        </mvc:interceptor>

    </mvc:interceptors>

        <!-- Cookie Resolver -->
    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**InternationalizationDemoController.java:**

```
package com.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class InternationalizationDemoController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/login.html")
    public ModelAndView getAdmissionForm(){
        ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView("Login");
        modelView.addObject("headerMsg", "Please enter below details to login");
        System.out.println("Inside InternationalizationDemoController..");
        return modelView;
    }

}
```

**Login.jsp:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

Select Language : <a href="?lang=en">English</a> | <a href="?lang=de">German</a> | <a href="?lang=it">Italian</a>

<form action="/FirstSpringMVCAnnotations/login.html">
  <div class="container">

    <h1 align="center">Login Page</h1>
    <p>${headerMsg}</p>
    <hr>

    <spring:message code="spring.username.label" />
    <input type="text" name="username"><br><br>

    <spring:message code="spring.password.label" />
    <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>

    <button type="submit" class="submitbtn">Submit</button>
    <button type="reset" class="resetbtn">Reset</button>
  </div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I have message_en.properties, message_it.properties and message_de.properties files in /Web-Inf folder.

**message_en.properties**

```
spring.username.label=User name
spring.password.label=Password
```

**message_de.properties**

```
spring.username.label=Nutzername
spring.password.label=Passwort
```

**message_it.properties**

```
spring.username.label=Nome utente
spring.password.label=Parola d'ordine
```

As displayed in below image, on click of German Language also it is showing User name and Password labels in English.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `<mvc:mapping path="/init" />` to `<mvc:mapping path="/**" />`.